# Implementation of emoji keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, emoji, emoticons

I want to insert animated(GIF) emojis to  chatlist for my android chat appication.

I have taken reference from https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon and added to my application. This is working fine, but I want to add my own emoji icon package and unicode for each emoji icon.

It would be great if anyone can help

Comment: explain what you want question clear